# Wagtail Admin api call for fetching child pages returns 0 in the explorer

Tags: wagtail

I updated wagtail to the latest version 2.6.1 from 2.4 and noticed that the API call that fetches child pages for displaying in the ADMIN UI explorer now returns 0 pages.

`admin/api/v2beta/pages/?child_of=1&for_explorer=1`

[image]

```
{meta: 
    {total_count: 0}, 
        items: [], 
        __types: {}}
    items: []
    meta: {total_count: 0}
    total_count: 0
    __types: {}
```

Is  there anyway around this?

Comment: Have now opened a bug report for this on Wagtail's issue tracker: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/5585

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this can happen if your project has a custom value set for Django REST Framework's `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` setting. In this case, Wagtail's admin API will end up returning results based on the specified authentication method, rather than the current logged-in user.

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/5585#issuecomment-543313909

To fix, add `'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'` to your `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` setting. A new release 2.6.3 will likely be out in the next few days to address this.

Answer (score 1):

This has been reported by a couple of other users on Wagtail 2.6 (see also [Menu navigator disappeared after upgrading to Wagtail 2.6 (from 2.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58137551/menu-navigator-disappeared-after-upgrading-to-wagtail-2-6-from-2-5)), but so far it hasn't been pinned down to a reproducible test case.

If you're seeing this bug on a local development build, and you're confident with git and `pip`, then one thing that would be really useful for tracking this down would be to set up a local development copy of Wagtail 2.6 as per the documentation at https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/contributing/developing.html, and run `git blame` over the `stable/2.6.x` branch to find the commit that caused this bug. (Note that if you're just looking at the API output, you can safely skip the `npm` build steps, as they're only needed for building the CSS/JS for the admin backend.)

I suspect https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/commit/7c9c00ab7c791e69dc3476a7298783f875f00c21 (pull request [#5069](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/5069)) may be the culprit, but it would be good to get confirmation.