# Menu navigator disappeared after upgrading to Wagtail 2.6 (from 2.5)

Tags: wagtail

We recently updated our Wagtail site and the page selector drawer is now blank.
I don't see any JavaScript errors or server-side errors.

Just looking for help on what I should be investigating. I can confirm this doesn't happen on a fresh install of Wagtail 2.5. I've also run `fixtree`.

[image: empty page nav tree]

Comment: I wonder if what you've encountered is related to this issue:  https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/5492

Comment: I think this is something separate to https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/5492 . It's also been reported at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57825908/wagtail-admin-api-call-for-fetching-child-pages-returns-0-in-the-explorer and on the Wagtail support Slack, but we haven't been able to pin it down to a reproducible test case yet. It's possible that it was a result of this change https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/5069 , but it's hard to see how that change would break things for superusers.

Comment: @gasman, could this have anything to do with the API not returning the root page? I saw I'm having the same problem as the question you posted to - but when I remove `&for_explorer=1`, it does return the pages.
https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/882f8f3cf8ddd79c30e611a48882b309e90dad0c/wagtail/admin/api/endpoints.py#L76-L78

Comment: @MichaelHarrison Yes, that seems likely. I've added some suggested troubleshooting steps at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58138837/1853523.

Comment: @gasman, I think I might have found a problem here: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/17e541715a80a43bc4eb1f1b07183bf22bb1869a/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/options.py#L52

I'll keep plugging away on trying to find what's happening.

In the meantime, we can't have our admin broken, so I've subclassed `PagesAdminAPIEndpoint` and removed the `ForExplorerFilter` from the filter backends.

Comment: @MichaelHarrison OK, thanks for investigating! If you do find that the problem goes away when removing specific features of your project (modeladmin definitions, hooks, third-party add-on apps) then that's really useful information to know too.

Comment: Have now opened a bug report for this on Wagtail's issue tracker: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/5585

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wagtail Admin api call for fetching child pages returns 0 in the explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57825908/wagtail-admin-api-call-for-fetching-child-pages-returns-0-in-the-explorer)